# Python: row level calculations inside if statements

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create indexes (*Recurring Field*) based on conditions (*Year, Month and Amount*) inside data. Example:

| Year | Month | Amount | Recurring |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 3 | 100 | 1 |
| 2020 | 10 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2020 | 11 | 1000 | 2 |
| 2020 | 12 | 1000 | 3 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2021 | 3 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2021 | 5 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2019 | 7 | 10000 | 1 |

The logic I'm trying to create is:

```
If the current row of Year is equal the previous row of Year then check 
if the current row of Amount is equal to previous row of Amount if it is true 
check if the previous row of Month is not equal to the current row of Month-1, 
if it is true then 1 else use the previous value of Recurring+1, everything else 1. 
Follows below a simple formula that runs on Excel: 
   =IF(A2=A1,IF(C2=C1,IF(B1<>(B2-1),1,D1+1),1),1)
```

Follows below the code that I'm trying to run in Python:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_pivoted)):
    if df.loc[i+1 ,'Year'] == df.loc[i ,'Year']:
        if df.loc[i+1 , 'amount'] == df_.loc[i , 'amount']:
            if df.loc[i , 'Month'] != df.loc[(i+1)-1 , 'Month']:
                df.loc[i, 'Recurring'] = 1
            else:
                    df.loc[i, 'Recurring'] = df.loc[i+1, 'Recurring']
        else:
                df.loc[i, 'Recurring'] = 1
    else:
            df.loc[i, 'Recurring'] = 1
```

Can someone help me out here? I am new to python and I don't know what can I do to get this working fine.
Regards.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, what is the index for your `df`?

Comment: It runs but the output is not the wanted. Numbers are wrong.

Comment: What is the index for your DataFrame?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Check the output of `df.index`

Comment: In the example, shouldn't `recurring` be 1 for 2020/11 and 2 for 2020/12?

Comment: Also, the logic of checking same year, 1 difference for month, won't work for December and January of the next year.

Comment: @not_speshal RangeIndex(start=0, stop=13028, step=1)

Comment: @JeanCruz - I think Junuxx's question is also very valid. What is the logic behind the "Recurring" column? What are you trying to get here? In plain English, without Excel/Python logic

Comment: @Junuxx you were right, I pasted it wrongly. Just fixed the post. Thanks

Comment: @not_speshal I need to replicate the results in Recurring using Python instead of Excel... As you saw my DB is way bigger than the example... Basically, if a bill has the same amount and it was billed in following months it should count then 1..2..3.. etc, if the year or month or amount changes, i need to start counting again...

Comment: I posted an answer based purely on the logic you explained in the question. But as Junuxx mentioned, this logic does not work when you from year 2019 month 12 (Dec 2019) to year 2020 month 1 (Jan 2020). So your "recurring" values basically reset every year.

Comment: @not_speshal it worked fine! thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this is what you need:

```
df.at[0, "Recurring"] = 1
for index in df.index[1:]:
    if df.at[index, "Year"] == df.at[index-1, "Year"] and df.at[index, "Amount"] == df.at[index-1, "Amount"] and df.at[index, "Month"] == df.at[index-1, "Month"]+1:
        df.at[index, "Recurring"] = df.at[index-1, "Recurring"]+1
    else:
        df.at[index, "Recurring"] = 1
```